# Return View With Generic Result using Async Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, generics, asynchronous

I am using an async method to return a Generic result using the code below but I am getting the following error:

> Error: "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[IMS.ViewModel.BranchVM]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[IMS.ViewModel.BranchVM]'"

```
public async Task<'ActionResult'> ViewBranches()
{            

    UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
    var currentUser = userManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

    var result = await db.ExecuteQueryAsync<object, List<BranchVM>>("GetBranches", new { CompanyId= currentUser.CompanyId});

    return View(result);
}
```

And in the Razor View:

```
@model List<IMS.ViewModel.BranchVM>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Branches";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutSMS.cshtml";
```

Comment: Well `ExecuteQueryAsync` is returning a list of lists, are you sure that's right? Maybe the generic parameter you give it just needs to be `BranchVM` instead of `List<BranchVM>`? But since you don't show us what that is, we can only guess.

Comment: thnx I used "<BranchVM" instead of "List<BranchVM>" and its solved my problem.